# my navbar/header is too small i wanna make it bigger what can i do?

Tags: html, css

My navbar is too small i wanna make it bigger. i dont know how can ı resize it or how can ı change navbar size i tried to change width and height but didnt work.  there are my html&css codes below. any help appricated.

```css
#navbar{
    color: #ffff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 0.75rem;
    height: 70px;
    
}
#navbar ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
#navbar ul li a {
    padding: 0.7rem;
}
#navbar ul li a:hover {
    background: rgb(226, 109, 128);
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.container{
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.bg-dark-blue{
    background: rgb(216, 152, 163);
}
```

```html
 <header class="bg-dark-blue">
    <div class="container">
        <nav id="navbar">
        <h1 class="heading-small"> Buse Nur Çetin</h1>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">  Ana Sayfa</a></li>
            <li><a href="hakkımda.html">Hakkımda</a></li>
            <li><a href="projelerim.html">Projelerim</a></li>
            <li><a href="fotogaleri.html">Fotogaleri</a></li>
            <li><a href="iletisim.html">İletişim</a></li>
            
          
          </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
 </header>
```

Comment: Can you edit this to be a code snippet? Also, it's worth noting that within the container div, the child content is constrained to the height of their parent unless you force it out.

Comment: What do you mean by "bigger"? Bigger text, height, padding?

Comment: @IvanBeliakov I think he wants the height to be 70px, but since the container class isn't given a height, it's likely constraining the nav element. He should set a height value for the container class

Comment: navbar size. @IvanBeliakov

Comment: @BuseNur we need you to elaborate on that. Do you want a height greater than 70px? What specifically are you looking for?

Comment: I still don't understand. You set #navbar height to 70px. If you want it bigger, change this value??

Comment: yes basically but when i change height navbar size doesnt change + i added code snippet @Kwright02

Comment: tried. didnt work @IvanBeliakov

Comment: I copied your HTML and CSS into a codepen and there the height changes when I modify the styles for #navbar. Perhaps try to refresh page with Ctrl + F5 to make sure you have no problem with cache?

Comment: thank you. nothing changes. still same@IvanBeliakov

Comment: Then please make a code snippet in your question so that we can see how your navbar is displayed

Comment: @BuseNur we need more context. If this stuff isn't working, then either you're using a framework that's doing something screwy, or you're not changing the right value.

Comment: okay i got it i have 2 css files. one of em is main.css other is mobile.css and somehow when i change mobile.css's navbar height all navbar height is changes @IvanBeliakov thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem in your CSS. You can set the height of your navbar in the styles for `#navbar`. This is the code snippet with your styles:

```css
#navbar {
  color: #ffff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 0.75rem;
  height: 70px;
}

#navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#navbar ul li a {
  padding: 0.7rem;
}

#navbar ul li a:hover {
  background: rgb(226, 109, 128);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.bg-dark-blue {
  background: rgb(216, 152, 163);
}
```

```html
<header class="bg-dark-blue">
  <div class="container">
    <nav id="navbar">
      <h1 class="heading-small"> Buse Nur Çetin</h1>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">  Ana Sayfa</a></li>
        <li><a href="hakkımda.html">Hakkımda</a></li>
        <li><a href="projelerim.html">Projelerim</a></li>
        <li><a href="fotogaleri.html">Fotogaleri</a></li>
        <li><a href="iletisim.html">İletişim</a></li>


      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

And this is the same snippet with different height for `#navbar`:

```css
#navbar{
    color: #ffff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 0.75rem;
    height: 120px;
    
}
#navbar ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
#navbar ul li a {
    padding: 0.7rem;
}
#navbar ul li a:hover {
    background: rgb(226, 109, 128);
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.container{
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.bg-dark-blue{
    background: rgb(216, 152, 163);
}
```

```html
 <header class="bg-dark-blue">
    <div class="container">
        <nav id="navbar">
        <h1 class="heading-small"> Buse Nur Çetin</h1>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">  Ana Sayfa</a></li>
            <li><a href="hakkımda.html">Hakkımda</a></li>
            <li><a href="projelerim.html">Projelerim</a></li>
            <li><a href="fotogaleri.html">Fotogaleri</a></li>
            <li><a href="iletisim.html">İletişim</a></li>
            
          
          </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
 </header>
```

Comment: probably something wrong with my other codes coz i've tried this like for 10 times and none of them worked

Comment: Try providing more code in your question

Comment: okay i got it i have 2 css files. one of em is main.css other is mobile.css and somehow when i change mobile.css's navbar height all navbar height is changes

Comment: For mobile version you can use CSS `@media`. If you have two files that set styles for the same element like `#navbar`, then the last file linked in HTML will be applied